# Сохранение изображения в консольном приложении

Tags: c#, изображения, .net-core

Есть консольное приложение на C# (небольшая утилита на .Net Core). Как на основании посчитанных данных (Набор цифр, на основании которых можно построить линии) сформировать и сохранить картинку произвольного размера (тип, в данном случае, не имеет значения)? И что лучше всего для этого использовать?

Должно получиться что-то типа этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока нашел вариант с BitMap'ом.

Comment: Что подразумевается под посчитанными данными? Что должно содержаться в картинке? Скриншот области экрана, сгенерированное изображение с циферками типа капчи, что? Вопрос непонятен.

Comment: Набор цифр, на основании которых можно построить линии. Должно получиться что-то типа этого:
http://www.obedience.org.ru/data/schema/202_5.jpg
Пока нашел вариант с BitMap'ом.

Comment: Используете либо System.Drawing, либо возможности WPF. Я бы выбрал второе. Вот вам для начала: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/774772/218063

Comment: Спасибо, попробую