# редактор текста на картинке WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно реализовать функционал редактирования текста на С# как в графических редакторах, например paint. У пользователя возможность перемещать текст, изменять его, выбирать цвет, размер, а затем сохранять в .jpg файл вместе с фоновой картинкой. 
Можете подсказать решение этой задачи? Достаточно из текста и Bitmap посредством действий пользователя получить другой Bitmap, с текстом на картинке.

Comment: В чем конкретно у вас проблема? Пока выглядит как дубликат этого: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/774772/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP Основная проблема - сделать так, чтобы пользователь в реальном времени двигал мышкой этот текст по картинке, набирал его, менял размеры текста и т.д. Например, как textBlock в интерфейсе Blend. Есть идея завязать на MouseDown и координате мышки, но мне кажется, это колхоз в данном случае.
Спасибо за ссылку. Думаю, в том посте как минимум половина моей задачи решена.

Comment: Ок, вот тогда вторая половина: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/863379/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP Спасибо!